# How do you obtain the actual polynomial function associated with a PDF curve in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing an experiment in school where I am analyzing the effects that twisting a wind turbine rotor blade has on the amount of power that the turbine outputs.

In my experiment, I performed 50 observations each, where I bent one of the turbine's rotor blades by a specific amount (in degrees), and then monitored the mean power output for a 2 minute period of time. My data set looks something like this

```
X1P_Train_Arrange <- data.frame(
  Mean = runif(250),
  Degree = sample(c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4","5"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I then used the geom_density function to create graphs of the PDF for each degree amount that I bent the rotor blade by when performing the experiment.

```
Mean_Density <- ggplot(X1P_Train_Arrange, aes(x = Mean, color = Degree)) + 
                geom_density(lwd = 2.0) +
                labs(title = "Mean", x = "Mean", y = "Density") +
                theme_minimal() + theme_Publication()
```

Now, my question is, is there any way to obtain the actual polynomial function associated with each colored curve when the data is plotted?
Thanks in advance for any help or assistance.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have edited my question based upon your recommendations.

Comment: Do you actually want an algebraic equation for each curve or do you just need to be able to determine the height of the curve at any given value of `Mean` and `Degree`?

Answer (score 1):

A [Kernel Density Estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) is not a polynomial function.

But you can reconstruct the actual function if you wish.

Note that a KDE is just a sum of many Gaussian distributions centered on your data points each with some bandwidth chosen by the algorithm. So all you need is the bandwidth and then you can put it all together. The bandwidth is just the standard deviation of the Gaussian distributions which make up the KDE. A wider bandwidth makes a smoother curve but leads to a loss of features. Too small and the curve is too ragged. So it is an optimization problem.

I suspect with `ggplot` you can supply your own bandwidth but to get one out I think best bet is to first fit your own using the `density` function. Once you do so you can see the value of `$bw`. Once you know the bandwidth, you just create a function which is the sum of many normal density functions centered on your data points each with a standard deviation of `bw`.

For example:

```
randomNumbers <- rnorm(100)
densityObject <- density(randomNumbers)

individualKernals <- lapply(randomNumbers, function(centerOfKernal){
  #return a function here, not a value
  function(x){dnorm(x, mean = centerOfKernal, sd = densityObject$bw)}
})

reproducedFunction <- function(x){
  toAverage <- sapply(individualKernals, function(f){f(x)})
  mean(toAverage)
}

plot(densityObject)

someXRange <- densityObject$x
y <- sapply(someXRange, reproducedFunction)

lines(x = someXRange, y = y, col = rgb(1,0,0,0.3), lwd = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insightful advice, could I trouble you some additional advice on how to write a function to sum the individual normal density functions after I obtain the $BW value?

Comment: See my update above. If you found the answer useful you should upvote it, and accept it as the correct answer so that others may benefit.

Comment: Chechy, thank you so much again. I was able to reproduce the results of the function that you provided. However, I was wondering if I could get some points of clarification from you. 1.) What is the meaning of the output of lines, in the last line of code? When I run that line of curve, it seems to produce another density curve? What does this curve mean?

Comment: Most welcome. Points of clarification are what the comment section is for...

Comment: 2.) What is the meaning of the y input in the 2nd to last line of code?

Comment: `y` is just the density. I just called it `y` because it controls the location on the y-axis.